# Error al usar la cláusula LIMIT con PDO en PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy intentando hacer un **SELECT**, donde entre otras cláusulas, uso la de **LIMIT**:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, telefono, dni FROM clientes WHERE usuario = ? AND nombre LIKE ? AND telefono LIKE ? AND dni LIKE ? LIMIT ?, ?";
$stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$id, $name, $tel, $dni, $from, $rows]);
$customers = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Antes de terminar, aclarar que he probado el código sin la parte del limit y funciona correctamente, además, también he hecho un `var_dump()` de los valores que le paso al **LIMIT** y son los siguientes:

```
$from = int(0)
$rows = int(10)
```

El problema es que básicamente al usar el **LIMIT**, pasa de darme más de 17 registros a **darme 0 registros**.

Otra prueba que he realizado, es cambiar `$from` por un 0 y `$rows` por 10, y tampoco hay resultados, a diferencia de cuando modifico directamente los **`?`** del select por los mismos valores, 0 y 10, donde sí me aparecen los resultados.

Comment: ¿Estás usando consultas preparadas? Muestra cómo haces el binding de los valores.

Comment: Por favor completa tu pregunta con el código que estas usando para poder ofrecerte una respuesta

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí, así es. He puesto todo el código y también tienes el var_dump() de las variables que dan el problema. Gracias!

Comment: @Aprendiz ¡Hecho, gracias!

Comment: Muestra las otras variables, yo creo que tu problema estaría más bien en los `LIKE`. Para depurar saca por pantalla cuál es el error: `print_r($db->errorInfo());`

Comment: @A.Cedano Sé que es muy raro, pero acaba de borrar todas las condiciones excepto el LIKE y tampoco funciona, y quitando el LIKE todo va bien. El print_r no me da esto: `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Comment: Ya encontré el problema, ahora te lo escribo en respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [`phpdelusions` reportan un problema con la cláusula `LIMIT` y PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#limit): **cuando las preparacciones emuladas están encendidas (`true`)  no es posible pasar en el array de `execute` valores para la cláusula `LIMIT`**.

> Otro problema está relacionado con la cláusula SQL LIMIT. Cuando está
>   en modo de emulación (que está activado por defecto), PDO sustituye
>   los marcadores de posición con datos reales, en lugar de enviarlos por
>   separado. Y con el enlace "perezoso" (usando array en `execute()`),
>   PDO trata cada parámetro como una cadena. Como resultado, la consulta
>   preparada con `LIMIT ?, ?` convierte en `LIMIT '10', '10'`, que es una
>   sintaxis no válida que hace que la consulta falle.

De hecho se produce un error parecido a este:

```
 Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
 violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
 that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
 use near ''0', '5'' at line
```

Dos soluciones son posibles:

### 1. Apagar las preparaciones emuladas

Si en la configuración de `PDO` estableces las preparaciones emuladas a `false`, o sea, las apagas, te funcionará.

En el contexto en el que estás, puedes apagarlas haciendo esto:

```
 $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

No obstante, **conviene que apagues las preparaciones emuladas en la conexión misma**, o sea cuando creas las instancias de `$db`, ahí puedes pasar un array de opciones como cuarto parámetro de `new PDO()` que incluya este valor: `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false`, así, cada vez que conectes a PDO quedarán apagadas.

Es **IMPORTANTE** hacerlo, en [mi respuesta sobre la *Inyección SQL*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967) se demuestra que, en ciertos escenarios, aunque uses consultas preparadas, te pueden colar código malicioso *emulando* consultas preparadas engañosas.

### 2. Usar marcadores de `:nombre`

Esta solución también es fáctible como bien indica @Aprendiz en su respuesta. Aquí los datos se pasan uno a uno y no se produce el error de sintaxis que provocaría el uso de  `LIMIT ?, ?`:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, telefono, dni FROM clientes WHERE usuario = :usuario AND nombre LIKE :nombre AND telefono LIKE :telefono AND dni LIKE :dni LIMIT :offset, :limit";    
$stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":telefono", $tel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":dni", $dni, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":offset", $rows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":limit", $from, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$customers = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

Al margen de otras propestas, te recomiendo lo siguiente:

- Ya que usas PDO, me parece que los marcadores a usar son de nombre, es decir con esta sintaxis: `:foo`
- Usa `bindParam()` con los siguientes atributos para indicar los valores que se interpolarán:

  - `:foo` que será el marcador de nombre
  - `$foo` que es la variable que trae el valor a interpolar
  - `PDO::PARAM_INT/PDO::PARAM_STR` que nos indica el tipo de dato esperado traiga la variable a interpolar

De tal manera que tu consulta pudiera quedar así:

```
$id  = 1;
$name = "bar";
$tel = 9784433439;
$dni = "gdffd786556";
$from = 1;
$rows = 2; 

$stmt= $db->prepare($sql = "SELECT id, 
                                   nombre, 
                                   telefono, 
                                   dni 
                            FROM clientes 
                            WHERE usuario = :id 
                            AND nombre LIKE :name 
                            AND telefono LIKE :tel 
                            AND dni LIKE :dni 
                            LIMIT :rows, :from");
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":tel", $tel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":dni", $dni, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":rows", $rows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":from", $from, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$customers = $stmt->fetchAll();
```